# Filter ArcGIS REST services features with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.22.

I am able to load and view vector features from ArcGIS REST services without any issues and from multiple sources. However, QGIS does not allow me to **filter** these features as  one can do with WFS features, vectors in geopackages, etc. [**Filter** is accessed by right clicking on the layer in question]. The functionality is important in that it allows one to reduce the size/number of features of a layer to a more manageable amount. Is this a known limitation of QGIS or a setting issue in REST services? Is there a known solution?

Since posting the question, I have discovered that 3.28 has solved the issue. I can successfully filter a vector geometry in a Rest Service using this version. This is documented in the changelog of the 3.28 release.

Comment: Are you trying to filter an image service or a feature service? Esri or OGC service? Please [Edit] the Question to clarify.